# Help with Broken battery cables

Tags: battery, battery-cable, grand-vitara

My daughter recently bought a 2003 Grand Vitara and the positive battery cable appears to have broken off. Would appreciate some assistance with identifying what part we need to purchase/replace.  It really just seems like the connection snapped at the terminal but I am not sure if the cables should be replaced too. [image]

Comment: It corroded off; be sure to cut back to good cable before attaching a new end as @ Solar Mike says.

Answer (score 1):

If the cable is till in good condition, then new battery terminals can be purchased which will solve the problem. This works as long as there is sufficient length still in the cable.

Other options include replacing the complete cable or fitting a terminal to the cable to bolt to the battery terminal.

Just need to work out what is best, personally I would fit a new battery terminal to the existing cable if it is long enough - it cannot be stretched tight like a guitar string...